# JQuery $.get() not calling remote URL

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a non-mvc application that needs to dynamically populate a select list, so I have a separately running MVC application to provide the data.

My MVC controller seems to be set up correctly:

```
     public JsonResult GetStateList()
 {

    var list = new List<ListItem>() {
    new ListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "VA" },
    new ListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "MD" },
    new ListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "DC" }
    };

     return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

And when I type the URL http:/localhost/TestMVC/home/GetStateList into the browser I get the JSON response.

The problem is when I am trying to use a $.get() from within the other program. My code is below and I know it's not hitting the controller since I am in debug mode and nothing hits.  Is my syntax incorrect?  Should I be calling it differently?

```
        $('#GetEmployeesByLetter').click(function() {

        var url = "http:/localhost/TestMVC/home/GetStateList";

        $.get(url, {}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
 var url = "http://localhost/TestMVC/home/GetStateList";
```

Two dashes after http - (//)

Anyway, you should never specify url like that, better to have root url,

```
$.get('/home/getstatelist', function (d) {
  // process data..
});
```

Comment: AAAAAAAHHHHHHH!  Thanks @alexanderb, I'm embarrassed that's what it was.  If you are in the SLC area I owe you a coffee.

Comment: unfortunatelly, I'm far far away from SLC :).. but accepting answer, would be nice !)

Comment: Better yet, use Url.Action("GetStateList", "Home"), in case you have the controller action mapped to a custom route.

Comment: @Tuan - Can't use Root URL, this is being called from a non-MVC app.